# Checking if something exists in json in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I've got a json API that I'm using like this:

```
[{
    "name": "Thing",
    "id": 1234,
    "total": 1,
    "stock": [
        {
            "size": "Small",
            "id": 1,
            "count": 10
        },{
            "size": "Medium",
            "id": 2,
            "count": 5
        },{
            "size": "Large",
            "id": 3,
            "count": 5
        }
    ]
}]
```

I'm looping over these in Vue, but want to check if anything exists in the 'stock' element outside of the `v-for` loop.

I can use `v-if` to check if the overall json exists, but can't seem to narrow it down to checking if the stock element contains anything.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a `v-if` & `v-else` condition on the length of the stocks array? If the length is greater than zero we have stocks, so display them, else, display a message. Something like this.

```
Vue.component('your-component', {
   template:
   `
   <div v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
      <p>{{ item.name }}<p>
      <p>{{ item.id }}<p>

      <div v-if="item.stock && item.stock.length > 0">
         <p v-for="(stock, j) in item.stock" :key="j">
            There'are {{ stock.count }} of size {{ stock.size }}.
         <p>
      </div>
      <div v-else>
         Ops... stocks not available.
      </div>
   </div>
   `,
   data () {
      return {
         items: []
      }
   },
   created () {
      fetch('your-api')
         .then((res) => res.json())
         .then((res) => { this.items = res })
   }
})
```

Comment: I tried that but both get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` when run.

Comment: If no stocks are available for a specific item, your API populates the `stock` field with an empty array or doesn't provide a `stock` field at all? Anyway, I updated the answer to catch both cases.